# what does enable-inline-optimization do when compiling php

Tags: php, php5

Can someone explain to me what exactly the --enable-inline-optimization option does when compiling PHP and why people would use it?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might check this [Wikipedia article on inline expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion) first to understand exactly what is meant by *inline optimization*. But essentially the compiler uses more memory (and generates a larger binary) to speed up the resulting program.

Here's a [post to the `php-dev` list](http://www.mail-archive.com/php-dev@lists.php.net/msg37203.html) describing in a bit more detail the affect this option has.

Comment: I see. So this does not necessarily help in to increase the performance of php scripts?

Comment: It could improve the performance of the PHP engine (Zend Engine), which in turn would improve the performance of the PHP scripts that it executes. (I don't know to what degree the performance could be affected, though – you'd have to test that.)

Comment: Ok thanks for the info.  If you have anything else to add, please do so. Thanks again.